# Data from server not changing after login with different user in angular

Tags: angular, authentication, httpclient

im building app with angular and use http request to the backend, but there is a bug and i dont know how this happen, my backend programmer too.

Example i login using account name "naoval"

[image]

then i click logout (of course i clean the localstorage when user logout)

and login using "admin" user account but this is what i get when i login using "admin" account

[image]

my app still showing my latest login user, i check the token for that 2 account, and it's the same token, but when i reload the page finally it's showing "admin" user

[image]

Here's my code

```
 // API services
  login(body: any) {
    return this._http.post(this.apiURL + 'login', body, {
      observe: 'body'
    });
  }
 login() {
    this.auth.login(this.loginForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log(data);
          this.successMessage = data;
          this.userService.getUserName().subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              if (data.data.kewirusType == 'user') {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/projects/all-project')
              } else if (data.data.kewirusType == 'admin') {
                localStorage.setItem('kewirusType', data.data.kewirusType);
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/admin/users-list');
              }
            }
          )
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.error.message[0]);
          this.errorMessage = error.error.message[0];
        }
      );
  }
  logout() {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
  }
```

why this is happening?

EDIT

Yes i have header component, and i subscribe to api like this

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.userData.getUserName().subscribe(
    data => this.user = data,
    error => console.log(error)
)}
```

and in my header html

```
<nb-user [nbContextMenu]="userMenu" size="medium" [onlyPicture]="userPictureOnly" name="{{ user?.data.displayName }}" [picture]="user?.data.photoUrl" nbContextMenuTag="my-context-menu">
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code that actually **displays** the wrong username. Besides, instead of two nested `.subscribe` blocks, use `.login().pipe(switchMap((data) => { /* the part where you set the localStorage; */ return this.userService.getUserName()).subscribe(..)`

Comment: i added header component, how i subscribe and display it on my header

Answer (score 1):

Your header-component don't detect the change in localStorage (sure if you press F5 you'll see "admin")

I suppose you has a header-component and a login-component so you can add a subject in your login service

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs'
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators'

userChange:Subject<any> =new Subject<any>()
```

And in login you can use pipe(tap)

```
  this.auth.login(this.loginForm.value).pipe(
      tap(res=>this.userChange.next(res.data))
      .subscribe(.....)
```

Then, in your header component

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this.loginService.userChange.subscribe(res=>{
     ..change the name..
   })
}
```

**Updated**

NOTE: I imagine you get the name of the user from localstore in ngOnInit, to not repeat code you can take anohter aproach.

In service, don't use pipe(tap). Simple add a method that you can call in subscribe

```
  //in your service
  loginSuccessfull()
  {
       this.userChange.next(res.data)
  }
```

Then, in your component, just, after store in localStore call this function

```
  this.auth.login(this.loginForm.value)
      .subscribe(
       .....
       //emit the subject if login calling the function
       this.auth.loginSuccessfull()
       )
```

And in your header-component use pipe(startWith)

```
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operators'

ngOnInit()
{
   this.loginService.userChange.pipe(
     startWith(null))
     .subscribe(res=>{
       ..get the name from localStore..
   })
}
```

NOTE: I believe that it's better store in localStore **in** service, then you can emit the value after store in localStore and you need'nt create the loginSuccesfull

```
login(body: any) {
    return this._http.post(this.apiURL + 'login', body, {
      observe: 'body'
    }).pipe(tap(res=>{
        ...store in localStore...
        this.userChange.next(res.data)
    });
  }
```

Comment: thats right i have header component, and i subscribe it to my services, and display it on my header like in my EDIT

Comment: i'm little confuse, `this.auth.login` is on `login.component.ts` and `userChange` on my `user.service.ts` and on my header i subscribe to userChange on `user.service.ts`? or to my `login.component.ts`

Comment: @naoval.is logic, because I didn't understand your problem. I just update the answer (change the update and add a new observation). It's only a particular case of https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: `this.userChange.next(res.data)` is storing my subscription to localstorage?

Comment: NO, this.userChange.next make that all the components that has `authservice.userChange.subscribe(res=>{.code..})` execute the code inside subscription

Comment: on `loginSuccessfull()` there is `(res.data)` where is it from?